# Why starred list contains zero song when here is more?

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

After executing request starred list I am getting zero tracks count when in reality it contains 26 tracks (image attached). Why it returns zero tracks?

```
    SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
    [SPTPlaylistSnapshot requestStarredListForUserWithSession:auth.session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistSnapshot *object) {
            NSLog(@"Starred :%@ tracks:%d",object.name, object.trackCount);
    }];
```

Output: **Starred :(null) tracks:0**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solved problem by adding **SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope** scope.

```
SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
[auth setRequestedScopes:@[SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope, SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope]];
```